# Cannot get Node js script started

Tags: node.js

I have installed node and nodejs, and I m testing with the simplest example.js, however when I type node example.js , nothing happens. Anything wrong with it?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
console.log('Server running at localhost:1337/');
```

Comment: I added the script there, it was the example code from nodejs website

Comment: You should at least see "Server running at localhost:1337/" on your console. You don't even get that?

Comment: nothing, and tried in browser, seems the server is not started at all.

Comment: How are you starting the script? Also provide what this reports: `node --version`

Comment: it gives nothing, but when I type whereis node, it gives me a directory "/usr/sbin/node"

Comment: Did you install it this way? https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os

Comment: What shows up when you just do `node` on terminal?

Comment: now it worked, i manually make and install the nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node), try to remove conflicting node installations you mentioned (node and nodejs), and then install one of them: **nodejs**

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs

# Confirm it worked
node --version       # v0.10.13
ls -la `which node`  # ... /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node
```